Experience Cloud user cannot access Activities object?
We have a custom report called "Assets with Events" where the report type have sources from Assets and Activities object. The issue is that when we log in to Experience as User to go to the report then that user is unable to see any fields in the Activities object while the fields from Assets object are visible.
After a few attempts, I realized it seems the user cannot access to any Assets record that has a Task activity or it will say: "It looks like you don't have access to this page. This feature will be introduced in the near future."
The user license is: Partner Community (ref: Experience Cloud User Licenses)
Checking in the Tasks object setting of the user's profile, I can see these fields there have Read Access checked in defaults.
I am very unfamiliar with this domain so I tried my best to describe my current issue. I hope someone can help me find out how I can make that user access with a full report.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387394&type=1

I tried add the Public field to both of my profile (can see IsVisibleInSelfService field = true) and the user profile but still cannot see the records or the Activities fields from the report. The login user method is "Log in to Experience as User". The weird thing is I tried another report type where Activities obj is the main source, then I can see and add fields from this object

The issue happens because we have set the Default External Access for the Activity object to 'Controlled by Parents'.
While according to the article 'Reports and Dashboards Limits and Allocations'
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rd_reports_dashboards_limits.htm&type=5

An object’s external organization-wide default must be set to private for an external user to view the object in a report. If an object's external organization-wide default can’t be set to private then an external user can’t view the object in a report.

Therefore go to Sharing Settings and change the setting to Private will make it work.
